# Fragments are not running perfectly in real device

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have used fragments to define a simple splitview, in the right site i used a layout containing videoview the xml code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/tvT"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

and in the left site in another fragment layout I have defined some buttons to play different videos, The program is running well in emulators, but when I run it on device, the videoview overlapped the whole area and creates a horrible look, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to post more of your code if you can; what you have posted isn't really enough for people to help you. [Edit: Darn, I thought this was trivial enough to be automatically moved to a comment on the original question :-\ ]

Answer (score 0):

May you could try with "fill_parent" because the video could be to big and uses the hole display:

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/tvT"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     />
```

If you can it would be good if you post some code how you setup your fragments.